# Upload Image impossible

Tags: migrations, media

I just migrated a website, and I can't upload any files now.
I checked the file path , it's ok
I checked the files and tmp permission , its ok (775)

When I try to upload an image, it does the 'ajax loading' and then boom everything's gone. It's like I just came and didnt try to upload anything.
I have no js , php or ajax error.

I really don't know what to do, have someone already face this ?

Thank you.

Comment: what does the server error log say?

Comment: Its your permission on your Files folder correct ?

Comment: like I said files and tmp folders are 775, and i don't have any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found the answer.
Files and tmp folders were owned by root, so I changed in www-data ( web user ) and everything works now.